# Access - Different queries based on blank values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a MS Access Database running a query which gets all employees from "TableX" that have the same Employee_Key from "TableY".

The issue is: some values from the column Employee_Key are blank. When this occurs I'm supposed to filter by Employee_Email, just like I'm doing with Employee_Key.

So, how can I verify either the Employee_Key is blank or not, and when it's actually blank, how do I run the another query with different filters (email)?

Ps: I don't have the exact query right now once this task is from my job.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. it's ok if you don't have the exact query - but this description is really hard to follow. If you could give us what you have so far (or even pseudo code) that would make it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select x.*
from tableX x
join tableY y on 
              (
                 '' not in (x.Employee_Key, y.Employee_Key)
                 and x.Employee_Key = y.Employee_Key 
              )
              or 
              (
                 '' in (x.Employee_Key, y.Employee_Key) 
                 and x.Employee_Email = y.Employee_Email
              )
```

Comment: Juergen, thanks alot for your response. It looks simpler than I thought. I'll try this and then I tell you :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the logic correctly:

```
select x.*, y.*
from tableX as x inner join
     tabley as y
     on x.employee_key = y.employee_key or
        (x.employee_key is null and x.employee_email = y.employee_email);
```

Comment: Gordon, your approach also seems very helpful. It's certainly gonna help me. Thank you very much.